# Using the contrapositive in lean 4

Tags: lean4, learning, natural-numbers

I'm trying to learn lean (version 4) by proving some basic facts about the natural numbers. Please feel free to critique my code if you see have general comments, but I also have a specific question involving a proof below. Here is my `nat` type:

```
-- Axiom 2.1. 0 is a natural number.
-- Axiom 2.2. If n is a natural number, then n++ is also a natural number.
inductive nat : Type | zero : nat | succ : nat → nat
```

I also have this axiom:

```
-- Axiom 2.4. Different natural numbers must have 
-- different successors; i.e., if n, m are natural 
-- numbers and n ≠ m, then n++ ≠ m++. Equivalently, 
-- if n++ = m++, then we must have n = m.
axiom succ_inj : ∀ n : nat, ∀ m : nat, n ≠ m → succ n ≠ succ m
```

I am using classical mode:

```
open Classical
```

I would like to use the contrapositive of axiom 2.4 (or a proof by contradiction) to prove the inductive step of this proposition

```
-- Proposition 2.2.6 (Cancellation law). Let a,b,c be natural 
-- numbers such that a+b=a+c. Then we have b=c.
theorem cancellation_law (a b c : nat) : (a + b) = (a + c) → b = c := by
  intro h
  induction a with
  | zero =>
    have h1 : b = zero + b := by rfl
    have h2 : c = zero + c := by rfl
    rw [h1, h2]
    exact h
  | succ a ih =>
    have h1 : succ a + b = succ (a + b) := by rfl
    have h2 : succ a + c = succ (a + c) := by rfl
    rw [h1,h2] at h
```

So now my lean state looks like this:

```
> case succ
bca: nat
ih: a + b = a + c → b = c
h: succ (a + b) = succ (a + c)
h1: succ a + b = succ (a + b)
h2: succ a + c = succ (a + c)
⊢ b = c
```

So now I would like to use the fact that

```
succ (a + b) = succ (a + c) -> a + b = a + c
```

which follows from axiom 2.4, and then apply the induction hypothesis. But I can't seem to figure out how to do a proof by contradiction. I continue the proof of proposition 2.2.6 with something like

```
have h3: a + b = a + c := by
...
...
contradiction
```

The *theorem proving in lean 4* book says the `contradiction` tactic looks for a contradiction in the hypotheses introduced, but how do I introduce an assumption for the purpose of contradiction? What is a good/canonical way to write this proof?

Here is a [MWE](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mwe.html):

```
open Classical

-- Section 2.1 The Peano axioms

-- Axiom 2.1. 0 is a natural number.
-- Axiom 2.2. If n is a natural number, then n++ is also a natural number.
inductive nat : Type | zero : nat | succ : nat → nat

namespace nat

-- Axiom 2.3. 0 is not the successor of any natural number; i.e.,
-- we have n++ ̸= 0 for every natural number n.
axiom zero_not_succ : ∀ n : nat, zero ≠ succ n

-- Axiom 2.4. Different natural numbers must have 
-- different successors; i.e., if n, m are natural 
-- numbers and n ≠ m, then n++ ≠ m++. Equivalently, 
-- if n++ = m++, then we must have n = m.
axiom succ_inj : ∀ n : nat, ∀ m : nat, n ≠ m → succ n ≠ succ m

-- Section 2.2 Addition
def add : nat → nat → nat
| zero, m => m
| succ n, m => succ (add n m)

-- Get to use the plus operator
instance : Add nat where add := add

-- Proposition 2.2.6 (Cancellation law). Let a,b,c be natural 
-- numbers such that a+b=a+c. Then we have b=c.
theorem cancellation_law (a b c : nat) : (a + b) = (a + c) → b = c := by
  intro h
  induction a with
  | zero =>
    have h1 : b = zero + b := by rfl
    have h2 : c = zero + c := by rfl
    rw [h1, h2]
    exact h
  | succ a ih =>
    have h1 : succ a + b = succ (a + b) := by rfl
    have h2 : succ a + c = succ (a + c) := by rfl
    rw [h1,h2] at h
/-
    > case succ
    bca: nat
    ih: a + b = a + c → b = c
    h: succ (a + b) = succ (a + c)
    h1: succ a + b = succ (a + b)
    h2: succ a + c = succ (a + c)
    ⊢ b = c
-/

end nat
```

Comment: Where do the theorem numbers come from?  Is this homework or are you following a proof from a logic book?  Also, you don’t need axiom 2.24 technically as Lean proves it for you automatically, see  https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/1664/122.

Comment: Could you improve your post by also including a complete [MWE](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mwe.html).  For example you are missing your definition of `+`.  This makes it possible for someone to copy-paste your code into Lean.

Comment: @JasonRute I'm following Tao's book Analysis I. I thought translating it into Lean would be a good way to learn. This is also why I have `succ_inj` written as it is, because that is more true to how its stated in the text, and I felt it should be possible to use the statements as given in Lean. I will update the question with a MWE, even though you have already answered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to answer your direct question, you can complete your proof with the following.

```
    apply ih
    contrapose h
    apply succ_inj
    exact h
```

After `apply ih` the goal is:

```
...
h: succ (a + b) = succ (a + c)
...
⊢ a + b = a + c
```

What `contrapose h` does is:

- Move the assumption `h` into the goal to get `succ (a + b) = succ (a + c) -> a + b = a + c`
- Swap the goal with its contrapositive.
- `intro h` to put the new assumption `¬ a + b = a + c` back into the assumption list.

To use [`contrapose`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Mathlib/Tactic/Contrapose.html) you have to import it from mathlib with `import Mathlib.Tactic.Contrapose`.

Now you can apply your `succ_inj` axiom.

---

Having said that, here are two points about `succ_inj`:

- It is almost always best to express injectivity as the contrapositive from the beginning.  So `succ_inj` would be `∀ n : nat, ∀ m : nat, succ n = succ m → n = m`.  This is much cleaner to work with.
- Injectivity follows directly from Lean's inductive types and is automatically created in this case as `nat.succ.inj` (using the version I just wrote in the bullet above).  See [here](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/1664/122) for how this works in Lean 3.  For Lean 4, it is a bit trickier to find the list of these automatically generated theorems since they aren't generated until you use them which can be done by calling them directly by name or invoking them with `simp`.

Now your proof doesn't have to rely on classical reasoning.  While your proof with `have` statements above works fine, I think this is a nice opportunity to use the `calc` tactic (which has the same syntax as the [`calc` command](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/quantifiers_and_equality.html?highlight=calc#calculational-proofs)).

```
theorem cancellation_law' (a b c : nat) : a + b = a + c → b = c := by
  intro h
  induction a with
  | zero =>
    calc
      b = zero + b := rfl
      _ = zero + c := h
      _ = c        := rfl
  | succ a ih =>
    apply ih
    apply nat.succ.inj
    calc
      succ (a + b) = (succ a) + b := rfl
      _            = (succ a) + c := h
      _            = succ (a + c) := rfl
```

---

Finally, while my calc proof is clean and easy to read, the book-ends of both `calc` were just `rfl` proofs.  Lean is actually smart enough to realize at that point that the goal and assumption `h` are definitionally equal, so we could just do this:

```
theorem cancellation_law'' (a b c : nat) : a + b = a + c → b = c := by
  intro h
  induction a with
  | zero =>
    exact h
  | succ a ih =>
    apply ih
    apply nat.succ.inj
    exact h
```