# Understanding noConfusion

Tags: lean, lean4

`Data.List.getLast` is defined as follows:

```
def getLast : ∀ (as : List α), as ≠ [] → α
  | [],       h => absurd rfl h
  | [a],      _ => a
  | _::b::as, _ => getLast (b::as) (fun h => List.noConfusion h)
```

I do not understand this definition, in particular the details around the recursive call.

1. Why is the last argument a lambda, when the signature seems to suggest a proof?
2. What is List.noConfusion, where is it defined, and how does it relate to the "No Confusion" rule in general?
3. Here's the type of List.noConfusion:

```
List.noConfusion.{u_1, u} {α : Type u} {P : Sort u_1} {v1 v2 : List α} (h12 : v1 = v2) : List.noConfusionType P v1 v2
```

How should I interpreter this? What is noConfusionType?

Comment: If it's any help, I wrote a blog post about the Lean 3 version of no_confusion here https://xenaproject.wordpress.com/2018/03/24/no-confusion-over-no_confusion/ . I believe that `List.noConfusion` is generated automatically by Lean 4 when you make `List`.

Comment: As to where `List.noConfusion` is defined see this answer: https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/1664/122.  However it is slightly different in Lean 4.  Namely these automatic theorems are hidden until they are used by some automation in Lean, like `simp` or what you are seeing.

Comment: Small correction:  It is just [`List.getLast`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Init/Data/List/BasicAux.html#List.getLast).  No `Data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "no confusion" in type theory is a characterizing property of constructors, say, if two terms of an inductive type are generated from different constructors, they should be unequal.

> Why is the last argument a lambda, when the signature seems to suggest a proof?

They are the same. `a ≠ b` is usually defined as `a = b → False`, which you usually prove via introducing a lambda.

> where is it (no confusion) defined

Seems like it's defined internally (correct me if I'm wrong).

The `noConfusionType` should be similar to something you generate in Haskell from `deriving Eq`, which is a two-arg pattern matching function that returns the unit type when `v1` and `v2` are of the same constructor and the empty type otherwise.

Comment: "no confusion" is *different* from "injective"! The three pillars of inductive types are "no confusion", "injective" and "occurs check" (and reflexivity), in the paper *Eliminating Dependent Pattern Matching*.

Comment: I love how computer scientists start counting at 0 ;-)

Comment: Edited to address the mistake 