# Peano Arithmetic in LEAN4

Tags: lean4, beginner, peano-arithmetic

Kia ora!

I am trying to implement the Peano axioms and prove some simple theorems about the natural numbers in LEAN4. However, I am not sure how to encode the first two [(as presented here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) axioms in LEAN. Namely, that zero is not the successor of any number and that the successor function should be injective.

This is how I have encoded the rest (without induction) of the axioms. This was all explained in Theorem Proving in Lean 4.

```
inductive Peano where
  | zero : Peano
  | succ : Peano → Peano
  deriving Repr

open Peano

def add (m n : Peano) : Peano :=
  match n with
    | zero   => m
    | succ n => succ (add m n)

instance : Add Peano where
  add := add

def mul (m n : Peano) : Peano :=
  match n with
    | zero   => zero
    | succ n => (mul m n) + m

instance : HMul Peano Peano Peano where
  hMul := mul
```

My first thought was to adjust the inductive definition to assert a witness to the fact that zero is not the successor of any number. Something like this:

```
inductive Peano where
  | zero          : Peano
  | succ          : Peano → Peano
  | zero_not_succ : ∀ x : Peano, zero ≠ succ x
  deriving Repr
```

LEAN was not happy with that, nor the analogous change for the injectivity of succ. Which makes sense because this is meant to be defining the elements of Peano, not properties of the elements.

Any help would be lovely! :)

Comment: In Lean, these will not be axioms but theorems, because they are already true about your structure `Peano`. Are you asking for help with stating the theorems, or also proving them? In any case, I think the chapters 3, 4 ought to cover the former, and the chapter 8 describes `noConfusion` which you'll need for the latter

Comment: My bad, the 8th chapter uses noConfusion, but doesn't explain it :/ anyway if you clarify I'll answer accordingly

Comment: There may be some small differences in the above answer because it is for Lean 3, but I think it gives you the main ideas.

Comment: Also this answer explains `noConfusion` for Lean 4: https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/2479/understanding-noconfusion?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @JasonRute thanks, that does help clarify the issue.

Comment: @JozefMikušinec To clarify, I am asking how they are proved in LEAN4.

Comment: The proof is rather easy: define a function that sends `0` to `True` and `1` to `False`. The trick is that proving that `True ≠ False` is easy.