# How to use the most bare essentials of Lean 4?

Tags: lean4, learning

As a learning exercise I want to use Lean 4 to prove theorems about natural numbers, but WITHOUT Mathlib (or as little as possible). I want to start with 2 Peano theorems s(x) != 0, and s(x)=s(y) -> x=y, and definitions ( x+0=x, x+s(y)=s(x+y), 1=s(0), x | y <-> Exists z y = x*z, etc. ). I want to use my own s,+,*,| but not any "built-in" definitions. I believe I need 'rw' (and all its options), and induction tactic, but (again) I do not want to use any library theorems (add_comm, etc. ) - I want to prove everything myself! I also want to use as few 'logical' constructs as possible - what is the bare minimum?

How do I get started? (I use "Lean 4 Web"). All reference tutorials quickly start using MathLib.

Comment: This isn't really how Lean works, as Lean's `Nat` has the Peano axioms built into the definition, and it would be the same if you defined your own `MyNat`. Both the [Natural Number Game](https://adam.math.hhu.de/#/g/hhu-adam/NNG4) and [Theorem Proving in Lean](https://lean-lang.org/theorem_proving_in_lean4/) teach stuff which doesn't essentially require Mathlib. (I guess NNG uses some tactics found in Mathlib, but similar tactics are in Lean core.) If you want to get into the bare-bone details of dependent type theory, chapter 1 of the [HoTT book](https://hott.github.io/book/) is good.

Comment: I think by "Mathlib" you just mean anything proved already in Lean even if it is in Lean core, like `Nat.add_comm`. The NNG is basically exactly that, where you have to prove a theorem in order to use it. You can also just define your own version of `Nat` by copying the definition (or even your own version of `=` if you feel adventurous) and prove things about it. If you want to be really bare bones, you don't need tactics at all.  You can just do term proofs. I think Theorem Proving in Lean does a decent job if you have a logical background of teaching you this stuff down to the logical core.

Comment: See https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/1661/in-lean-why-is-it-possible-to-prove-0-neq-1-without-adding-it-as-an-axiom

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to do this project to become acquainted with lean. I found enough information in [Theorem Proving in Lean 4](https://lean-lang.org/theorem_proving_in_lean4/) to get it done, to some degree. I had to ask a few questions on here, but TPIL4 had the answers in the end - I just didn't see them!

I am new to this too, but if you want to see what I did then you can go [here](https://github.com/SyntakticSugar/Numbers/tree/master/Numbers). Have fun :)

I realise this should probably be a comment - but I don't have the kudos for that!

Comment: Nice to see a novice stuggling like me ;).  I want to use Lean 4 to prove theorems starting with Peano's 2 axioms (using zero and s), then define add, mul, 1, 2, etc. and start then prove "add zero zero = zero" and "for all x  add zero x=x" which needs induction (similar to Tao's: 131ah.1.03w/week1.pdf). I do not want to use Lean lib on Nat (else things like 1, 2 "leak" into it!). If I don't use Lean's Nat induction, can I do it myself? I tried  structure Peano := P : Type s : Number → Number zero : number axiom_0 : ∀ x:Number,   s x  ≠ zero add : Number → Number → Number, etc.

Comment: What you did is very impressive! I formalized Peano Arithmetic (starting with 2 axioms) and finally proved infinity of primes. Needed about 60 theorems! BUT, I used a Theorem Prover (web SPASS) to do logic and equality. I plan to do something similar in Lean 4.

Comment: I also recommend [Functional Programming in Lean](https://lean-lang.org/functional_programming_in_lean/).